# How do i check if a string includes a blacklisted word that is in a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check if a string includes a blacklisted text that is in a mongodb collection.

I have tried the code below and it is not logging it to console even if it does include the blacklisted text.

```
const includesit = await blacklistwordtextthingschema.find({id: `${request.params.id}`});
if(JSON.stringify(request.body).includes(includesit.text)){
    console.log('INCLUDES!')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by making the blacklisted text into an array and pushing in the array instead of making a new document for every text.

```
const blacklistWord = await blacklistwordtextthingschema.findOne({ id: request.params.id });
if (!blacklistWord.text.some(v => JSON.stringify(request.body).includes(v))) {
 console.log("body does not include a blacklisted word!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blacklistWord = await blacklistwordtextthingschema.findOne({ id: request.params.id });
if (blacklistWord && request.body && request.body.someField.includes(blacklistWord.text)) {
    console.log('INCLUDES!');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get all of the documents that has the id and check if the request.body includes the text of the document, unfortunately this answer didn't work.